# ASP Identity and Owin - Token Generation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have the following :

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),                
};
```

Everything works fine, I need to call the **/token** with the arguments on the `request body` using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

My issue is that I have a requirement to allow tokens generation from a client that cannot send data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, she is only able to sent the arguments as Json, which according to OAuth 2 is not ok, and besides that the Microsoft Owin does not allow it.

How can I manually generate tokens for this purpose? I assume I should create a `webapi` method to do it, but how can I use the regular Microsoft Owin provider ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WebApi endpoint to work as a Proxy, which means that you would receive the arguments as JSON, and internally you can call the `/Token` converting parameters to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Take a look at http://restsharp.org/, it would ease your internal call to the token provider.